# Smoke coming out from the radiator

Tags: toyota, radiator, smoke

I have a 2008 Toyota Auris. Yesterday I was stuck in traffic, and I noticed that the temperature was getting high as time was passing by. At one point I had to stop because the temperature was at its highest point. When I opened the bonnet I could notice white smoke coming out of the radiator. I stopped the car and I let it cool down. When I opened the top of the radiator, a black jelly-like liquid came out of it. I let it cool for some hours and then I refilled the radiator with water, the temperature did not get very high but remained stable. The car worked perfectly well. Can you tell me what happened to my car, please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you lost your fans, which then caused it to overheat. No clue what the "black jelly-like liquid" is, but assume it must be engine oil, which would mean a blown head gasket. Sounds like it needs major surgery at this point.

Comment: Take it to a good shop - there are tests that can be done such as CO2 in the coolant to see if the headgasket is blown...

Comment: "Black jelly like liquid" sounds like a mousse of oil, water, and exhaust gas - and the one-word technical term for that is likely to be "expensive," unfortunately.

Comment: @SolarMike - I believe the tests for blown head gaskets you are talking about look for *hydrocarbons* in the coolant, which there should be absolutely none of if things are ship-shape ... but that's probably pedantic.